# Type definition of an array with named objects, with key values of string?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have two object type-defined as below and I am able to use them without any problem:

```
const apiURLs: { [key: string]: string } = {
  repoSearchURL: `https://api.github.com/search/users?q=`,
  repoURL: `https://api.github.com/repos/`,
  userURL: `https://api.github.com/users/`,
  userReposURL: `https://api.github.com/users/`,
};

const responseMessage: { [key: string]: string } = {
  unknownError: `Something went wrong`,
  emptyError: `There are no repositories`,
};
```

When I put them in an array as below:

```
const apiConstants: { [key: string]: object }[] = [
  {
    apiURLs: {
      repoSearchURL: `https://api.github.com/search/users?q=`,
      repoURL: `https://api.github.com/repos/`,
      userURL: `https://api.github.com/users/`,
      userReposURL: `https://api.github.com/users/`,
    },
    responseMessage: {
      unknownError: `Something went wrong`,
      emptyError: `There are no repositories`,
    },
  },
];
```

I got a type error as follows when calling any data:

```
Property 'apiURLs' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: object; }[]'.ts(2339)
```

1. Is there any way to define the type without declaring fixed key names?
2. What are my options by declaring as type or as an interface?

Comment: You're looking for `apiUrls` in your array, not your object, hence the error.

Comment: `{ [key: string]: { [key2: string]: string } }[]` should work

Comment: Suggest extracting to generic. `type Obj<T> = { [key: string]: T }`  then `const apiConstants: Obj<Obj<string>>[] = []`

Comment: You have an array [ ... with one object in it {.. Why do you need both? Just use an object perhaps? This looks odd too: `{ [key: string]: object }[] `

Comment: @JGFMK You are pretty right, the wrapping array is completely useless in here. I will be using more anonymous objects in the array but as you had highlighted. The array in this stage is not a good idea here. Please omit it and thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly Which would be a better practice, the straight approach or the approach with generic? Thanks.

Comment: Generic is always better